# How do I put Output command telnet in file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, telnet

How do I put Output command `telnet` in file ?

```
telnet www.google.com 80 > file.txt 
GET / /HTTP/1.1
```

Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct...I don't know why its not work, but you can use **tee** to.

```
command | tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

A slight modification will catch stderr as well:

```
command 2>&1 | tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

or just the same with less characters to type:

```
command |& tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

tee is useful if you want to be able to capture command output while also viewing it live.

Comment: what is the tee ~/outputfile.txt ?? 
give me a example please

Comment: Noooo telnet google.dz 80  > a.txt it's not correct !!

Comment: `telnet www.google.com 80 | tee file.txt`

Comment: I tested `telnet www.google.com 80 > file.txt` and works

Comment: Ohh Yeah thanx luiz lago